# Why is my Ajax code not working in IE8?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

My Ajax code does not work in IE8 but it works in Firefox. I have tried a couple different ways that people posted on the internet but none of them seem to work.

Here is my code that works, just not in IE8:

```
function populatematerial(str)
{
    if (str=="") {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
      return;
    }

    var xmlHttp = null;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
     // IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }

    else{
     // IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","GetMySQLData.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

In the PHP file it just gets data from the MySQL database to populate a new select method.

Comment: Better solution: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Just a tip: I'd recommend you use jQuery or similar ajax library that will take care of all the browser differences for you as well as give you decent errors when something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this part of the if statement: `&& xmlhttp.status==200` and you should be good (this seems to be a bug in IE)

Answer (score 0):

What type of error you are getting.. post the error message...

also make sure that there is no javascript function is returned from the php page.